# Test not looping in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a test that I'm trying to fix. It needs to click on each result and verify the price and name match from the initial result with the final individual result. Currently my code will click on only the first image but will not navigate back to the results page to try the next result. I tried to remove the `first()` as my understanding is that method only takes the very first element and ignores the rest. Sadly that didn't work. What am I missing?

```
tester.it('links to the correct product details page when a result is clicked', () => {
  const $offer = element.all(by.css('#main-results .catalog-offer')).first();
  const offerResultsText = [];
  let offerResultsPrice;

  return Promise.all([
                $offer.all(by.css('.offer-name .name-part')).map(($namePart) =>
                    $namePart.getText().then((partText) => offerResultsText.push(partText))
                ),
                $offer
                    .element(by.css('.price'))
                    .getText()
                    .then((offerPrice) => (offerResultsPrice = offerPrice)),
            ])
                .then($offer.element(by.tagName('a')).click)
                .then(() =>
                    browser.wait(
                        protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(
                            element(by.css('#recently-purchased-details'))
                        ),
                        5000
                    )
                )
                .then(() =>
                    expect(element(by.css('.details .subtotal > span')).getText()).to.eventually.equal(
                        offerResultsPrice
                    )
                )
                .then(() => {
                    return offerResultsText.map((sourceString) => {
          console.log(sourceString);
                        return expect(
                            element(by.css('.details .setting .info')).getText()
                        ).to.eventually.contains(sourceString);
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: if I were you, I would get rid of all occurrences of `Promise`, `.then` etc, and made it use `async/await`

Comment: Thanks Sergey! Yeah unfortunately since we don’t actually test on Angular we have to use the Tester Module as a shim which won’t allow us to use async await.

Comment: @KevinLeroy you don't actually have to be using Angular to use async/await. You can turn off the `waitForAngular` bit by doing this: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. If you do that, it doesn't matter if the app uses angular or not. In any case, do yourself and everyone who has to maintain this code a favor and refactor this. Not trying to be mean here, please take this as constructive criticism, the code you pasted above would be a nightmare to debug and maintain. Make it easier on everyone and simplify this in whatever way you can.

Comment: @tehbeardedone It's actually not so much Angular as it is the shim that is used to run Protractor. It requires us to use `then()`.

Comment: Well color me confused. You said since you aren't testing on Angular you have to use the Testing Module shim. Never heard of that before is all I'm saying. I can write some tests right now for a non Angular app using plain old Protractor without any extra plugins or shims.

Comment: @tehbeardedone I don't disagree with what you're saying. The decision to use this shim was in place far before I ever got here. Wasn't my decision to make. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. I needed to remove the `return` and then use our internal method afterward to loop through the results urls. Looked like this in the end...

```
expect(testerUtils.getPageId()).to.eventually.equal('Recently Purchased Engagement Ring Details');
testerUtils.go(testContext.url);
```